# Android 2.3.4, OpenSL ES and huge log-spamming for unknown reason

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-2.3-gingerbread, opensl

One app that I created causes extensive log-spamming on a device of a customer:

I use OpenSL in a NDK environment for realtime audio generation. Everytime I use the Enqueue() function of the SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf, android creates a log entry because that call implicitly calls play() on the audio interface.

This looks like that:

```
........app start........
06-05 21:36:48.619: I/System.out(10081): Debugger has connected
06-05 21:36:48.619: I/System.out(10081): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 21:36:48.819: I/System.out(10081): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 21:36:50.419: I/System.out(10081): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 21:36:50.619: I/System.out(10081): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-05 21:36:50.829: I/System.out(10081): debugger has settled (1491)
// ....some other unimportant logging stuff was here ....
06-05 21:36:53.359: D/execute(10081): Creating audio output OpenSLES
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Creating the engine
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Realizing engine
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): retrieving engine interface
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Creating output mix
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Realizing output mix
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Configuring audio source
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Configuring audio sink
06-05 21:36:53.369: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Creating audio player
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): realizing the player
// Who is that? I assume Android itself....
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioTrack(10081): Request AudioFlinger to create track
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Retrieving play interface
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): get buffer queue interface
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): registering buffer queue callback
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): Retrieving effect send interface
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioOutputOpenSLES(10081): getting volume interface
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/execute(10081): First process call...
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/execute(10081): Will start playback
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/play(10081): Starting playback
// And the show starts here: Every time I Enqueue audio data in my C++ code, this log entry appears.
06-05 21:36:53.379: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.389: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.409: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.609: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.629: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.679: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.739: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.759: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
06-05 21:36:53.819: D/AudioTrack(10081): start 0x1f7bf8
....... and so on
```

This is how I Enqueue a new audio buffer to OpenSLES:

```
bool SE::AudioOutputOpenSLES::enqueueBuffer( void* _buffer, unsigned int _byteSize )
{
    SLresult result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, _buffer, _byteSize );

    return( result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS );
}
```

OpenSLES doesn't complain about that call and returns SL_RESULT_SUCCESS.

I googled around a bit and found that the log entry comes from the Android source AudioTrack, which I found here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.2.3_r2.1/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp

At the beginning of the start() function is the logging:

```
LOGV("start %p", this);
```

But what keeps OpenSL to call play() implicitly everytime a new buffer is enqueued? I had a look in the spec of OpenSL here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.0.1.pdf

On Page 174 they say "When the player is in the SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING state, which is controlled by the SLPlayItf interface [see section 8.32], adding buffers will implicitly start playback. In the case of starvation due to insufficient buffers in the queue, the playing of audio data stops. The player remains in the SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING state. Upon queuing of additional buffers, the playing of audio data resumes. Note that starvation of queued buffers causes audible gaps in the audio data stream. In the case where the player is not in the playing state, addition of buffers does not start audio playback. "

As the phone isn't crackling, I assume that audio is still playing nicely and this description from the documentation sounds to me as if they ALWAYS implicitly start playback, which effectively means that there is no chance for me to prevent this log spamming.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO that depends a lot and changes from version to version of Android, from manufacturer to manufacturer..

I am not sure why end customer is bothered with log but I would just make filter in logcat to ignore it.. Simple solution is probably the best, especially when source of spam is in source of android :s

Comment: This would be the filter `^((?!AudioTrack).)*$`  , it will ignore logs with string AudioTrack.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it depends on device's vendor. Please try on different device, and probably you won't see these logs, but you could experience the different ones. You cannot do anything except adding filter to LogCat.